# Can you have multiple spyObjs in a beforeEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I am testing an Angular 1 application with Jasmine.  My question is, **is it possible to create two spies for two separate services in the same `beforeEach` statement?**

Right now I can get the first spy to work, but I'm not sure why the other spy isn't working.  I have the spies setup to where a promise is assigned to a global variable inside of them, which can be accessed in any of the tests.  So, the second variable is just returning as `undefined` instead of the expected promise.

Here is the sample set up code inside the `beforeEach`:

```
mockWorkingService = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockWorkingService', ['retrieve']);
mockWorkingService.retrieve.and.callFake(function(crit) {
    workingServiceDfr = $q.defer(); // $q is defined globally
    return workingService.promise;
});

mockFailingService = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockFailingService', ['retrieve']);
mockFailingService.retrieve.and.callFake(function(crit) {
    failingServiceDfr = $q.defer();
    return failingService.promise;
});
```

Also, `retrieve` is defined separately for each service.

Comment: You can of course have as many spies as you want. You'll want to provide a bit more context as to how your tests are set up for us to be able to help.

Comment: What other context would be necessary?  I know the problem is occurring in the beforeEach, and there's not much else there.  There are a bunch of global vars defined outside of the beforeEach inside the `describe` block, along with where the module is defined.

Comment: An example would be, how are you calling these services in your tests? On what line of code are you seeing "the second variable is just returning `undefined`"? See [mcve] if you'd like to understand the kind of information we'd like to see.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out, and then update the question.  I was just logging the value of `failingServiceDfr` after the last line of the sample code above, which was returning undefined (along with where it was being used in my tests). Whereas the other deferral was returning a value.  It feels like I'm missing something really obvious in my code. So before investing a bunch of time into making my question "elite" I'm going to spend some more time debugging.  Thank you!

Comment: try to reset the mockWorkingService  & mockFailingService  after the tests like in the afterEach(function(){// new mockWorkingService; new mockFailingService; }) just so that each test run gets a clean service & its collaborators

Comment: The problem is pretty odd (or silly) so I think this post is largely irrelevant.  I may delete it tomorrow.  There's no point spending a bunch of time making it very detailed when there's likely nothing relevant to find in the code I would provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "yes", you can have multiple spies in `beforeEach` statements.

Comment: Are you limited to only one spy per it() statement? Or can you have multiple spies within one test?